# Зенит в космосе

Tags: переводы

Есть в одной стратегии в космосе flak frigate против мелочи. Его перевели как *зенитный фрегат.* А есть в космосе зенит? Какой будет корректный перевод?

Answer (score 0):

Всё верно перевели (думал так сначала, смотрите конец ответа). Смотрите [Грамоту](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x):

**ЗЕНИТНЫЙ,** -ая, -ое. 1. *Астрон.* к Зенит (1 зн.). *З-ое расстояние.* **2. Предназначенный, служащий для стрельбы по воздушным целям.** *З. пулемёт. З-ое орудие. З-ая пушка. З-ая артиллерия.*

И [словарь Макмиллана](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/flak):

**flak**
<...>
**2. bullets or bombs that are shot at planes from the ground**

Но, как верно заметил Nektoid, в этой игре воюют не на Земле, а в самом космосе. Так что если так и есть, тогда такой перевод не подойдёт, надо ещё думать. Единственное, что на ум сразу приходит, это просто **космический фрегат.** :)

Comment: Так вот именно, что at planes from the ground. А в вопросе речь идёт о космическом фрегате. Да и какой зенит в космосе? Там же не воюют все в одной плоскости, диктуемой направлением притяжения.

Comment: Даже не подумал об этом, спасибо!

Comment: "космический фрегат" - в Homeworld много типов фрегатов, и все космические :)

Answer (score 0):

Flak можно перевести как *шрапнель* (например, flak jacket — бронежилет, защищающий только от осколков, в отличие от body armor — полноценного бронежилета с защитой и от пуль, и от осколков).
Поэтому flak frigate можно перевести как *"шрапнельный фрегат"*.

Comment: В том смысле, что он стреляет шрапнелью?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой ну да, я полагаю, что он стреляет чем-то разлетающимся. Обычно в играх flak используется скорее в значении оружия, стреляющего чем-то разлетающимся (это называется сплеш).

Comment: @Nektoid игра - Homeworld, и флак фрегат стрелял по мелким самолетикам. Можете видео посмотреть. FLAK с немецкого переводится как противосамолётная (зенитная) пушка.